# Margin and React Native Paper is not working

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-paper

I am trying to move the "three-dot" menu to the right side. So I put a {marginLeft: auto} for it. But, it's not moving to the right. What is the problem?

[image]

Also, there is another problem. When I press the 'three-dot' icon, I want to open a popup menu. To do that, I am using react native paper from https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/menu.html

The menu should be visible when the icon is pressed. But it's not working. What went wrong and How may I fix it?

[image]

Comment: try padding-right

Comment: I tried. It didn't work either.

Comment: Try converting the parent view to flexbox and use `space-between` property.

Answer (score 0):

The `left()` `right()` property of react native paper should help you to put your icon where you want.

Therefore, try to call arrow function in ur onPress to trigger ur action like `onPress={() => openMenu}` and if doesn't work try `onPress={openMenu()}`.